# Delete object element with forEach()

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have this code to remove element from object:

```
const data = {
    "fname": "xyz",
    "lname": "abc",
    "age": 23,
    "level_year": 555,
    "qty_min": 1,
    "qty_med": 2
};

['fname', 'age'].forEach(val => {
    console.log('??', val)
    delete data[val];
});

console.log('result', data);
```

Output:

```
[object Object] {
  level_year: 555,
  lname: "abc",
  qty_med: 2,
  qty_min: 1
}
```

I actually want to remove all element by using the same `key` so I did this:

```
const data = {
    "fname": "xyz",
    "lname": "abc",
    "age": 23,
    "level_year": 555,
    "qty_min": 1,
    "qty_med": 2
};

const obj1 = Object.assign({}, data);
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, data);

['fname', 'age'].forEach(val => {
    console.log('??', val)
    delete obj1[val];
    delete obj2[!val];
});

console.log('result1', obj1);
console.log('result2', obj2);
```

Update: I add `delete obj2[!val]` because I was expecting `obj2` to only keep `fname` and `age` element. Obviously I was wrong. Expected output for `obj2`:

```
[object Object] {
  "fname": "xyz",
  "age": 23,
}
```

`obj1` does removed the element but `obj2` does not. How can I solve this problem without using multiple `forEach()` and by using same object key? Preferably no library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `obj2[!val]` ----- > `!` ....... ???????????

Comment: what do you think `!val` would be, say when `val == 'fname'`? (hint: it's false)

Comment: @sg552 :  `obj2[!val]` ==> `obj2[false]`(since non-empty string is a truthy value) ==> `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the expected result, instead of cloning the data completely twice and deleting properties afterwards, you could add the properties only to wanted object:

```js
const data = {
    "fname": "xyz",
    "lname": "abc",
    "age": 23,
    "level_year": 555,
    "qty_min": 1,
    "qty_med": 2
};

const obj1 ={},obj2 ={}, props = new Set(['fname', 'age']);
Object.keys(data).forEach(p=> (props.has(p) ? obj2 : obj1)[p] = data[p]);

console.log('result1', obj1);
console.log('result2', obj2);
```

**edit**
About the line `(props.has(p) ? obj2 : obj1)[p] = data[p]`:

The first part `(props.has(p) ? obj2 : obj1)` checks if the props-[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the property named `p`. If it does, this snippet returns `obj2`, otherwise `obj1`

On that resulting object, the property index `[p]` is used to set the value. For example, for `fname`, `obj2` would be returned from the part above, resulting in `obj2[p] = ...`

The last part `data[p]` is simply to get the value of property `p` on the `data` object.

Comment: You got that correctly. `lname` is a typo. My apologies.

Comment: Just noticed you altered the post and removed the question from my post. Was kind of assuming it was a typo ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please explain what happen here `(props.has(p) ? obj2 : obj1)[p] = data[p])`? For example when `fname` exist in `props` then what happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, added it in the post. It can indeed be a bit of a daunting line. The main part is the conditional operator `(props.has(p) ? obj2 : obj1)`. For `fname` the line would resolve to `obj2['fname'] = data['fname']`

Comment: `props.has(p)` will equal to  `true` for `fname`, so isn't `obj2` is suppose to return and not `obj1`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: oops, my turn for a typo. I started the example with `lname`, but amended it to `fname` to match with your comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo,

```js
const data = {
    "fname": "xyz",
    "lname": "abc",
    "age": 23,
    "level_year": 555,
    "qty_min": 1,
    "qty_med": 2
};

const obj1 = Object.assign({}, data);
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, data);

Object.keys(data).forEach(val => {
    /*console.log('??', val)*/
    if (['fname', 'age'].indexOf(val) > -1) {
        delete obj1[val];
    }
    else {
        delete obj2[val];
    }
});

console.log('result1', obj1);
console.log('result2', obj2);
```

Comment: got your point..you want remove identical to obj1 in 2 right?

Comment: Your answer is correct. I do appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating new object without these properties and keeping original intact.

```
function omit(names, obj) {
  var result = {};
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (names.indexOf(prop) == -1) {
      result[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

and use it like
const data = { "fname": "xyz", "lname": "abc", "age": 23, "level_year": 555, "qty_min": 1, "qty_med": 2 };
const withoutProps = omit(['fname', 'age'], data)
```